# How to correctly manage feature configuration deployment in JBoss Fuse 6.2.1?

Tags: deployment, jbossfuse, fabric8

I am trying to evaluate JBoss Fuse as an integration platform, and I have the following question regarding deployment.

I am trying to set up a fabric and use profiles, more specifically feature repositories for camel/blueprint component deployment.
I am having the following issue with externalizing the component configuration: when i update the snapshot of the configuration file artifact, the configuration changes are not picked up by the container.

Moreover, when i completely remove the profile from the container, the PID config file stays on the server in etc/ folder.

Also there is an additional issue during deployment where the camel bundle gets activated before the config pid file is loaded, resulting in exception in aries blueprint, and i have to additionally refresh the osgi bundle manually.

Here is how the feature repository file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<features name="fuse-poc">  
    <feature name="fuse-poc-common" version="${project.version}">  
        <bundle>mvn:com.myorg.fuse/common/${project.version}</bundle>  
    </feature>  
    <feature name="fuse-poc-camel" version="${project.version}">  
        <feature>fuse-poc-common</feature>  
        <config name="com.myorg.fuse.poc.camel">  
            test.value=ENC(5XdDgfKwwhMTmbo1z874eQ==)  
        </config>  
        <bundle>mvn:com.myorg.fuse/fuse-poc-camel/${project.version}            </bundle>  
    </feature>  
    <feature name="fuse-poc-activemq" version="${project.version}">  
        <feature>fuse-poc-common</feature>  
        <configfile finalname="etc/com.myorg.fuse.poc.jms.cfg">  
            mvn:com.myorg.fuse/feature/${project.version}/cfg/dev  
        </configfile>  
        <bundle>mvn:com.myorg.fuse/fuse-poc-camel-    activemq/${project.version}</bundle>  
    </feature>  
</features>
```

The projects themselves are simple camel archetype projects with one having a basic route with logging and one with route using activemq and cm:property-placeholder in blueprint.xml

Here is the corresponding build section in maven:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
  <parent>  
  <groupId>com.myorg.fuse</groupId>  
  <artifactId>fuse-poc-parent</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
  </parent>  
  <artifactId>feature</artifactId>  
  <packaging>pom</packaging>  


  <name>FUSE PoC Feature Repository</name>  
  <build>  
        <resources>  
            <resource>  
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>  
                <filtering>true</filtering>  
            </resource>  
        </resources>  
  <plugins>  
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>2.6</version>  
                <executions>  
                    <execution>  
                        <id>filter</id>  
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>  
                        <goals>  
                            <goal>resources</goal>  
                        </goals>  
                    </execution>  
                </executions>  
            </plugin>  
  <plugin>  
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
  <version>1.10</version>  
  <executions>  
  <execution>  
  <id>attach-artifacts</id>  
  <phase>package</phase>  
  <goals>  
  <goal>attach-artifact</goal>  
  </goals>  
  <configuration>  
  <artifacts>  
  <artifact>  
  <file>target/classes/fuse-poc.xml</file>  
  <type>xml</type>  
  <classifier>features</classifier>  
  </artifact>  
                                <artifact>  
                                    <file>src/main/resources/env/dev/com.myorg.fuse.poc.jms.cfg</file>  
                                    <type>cfg</type>  
                                    <classifier>dev</classifier>  
                                </artifact>  
  </artifacts>  
  </configuration>  
  </execution>  
  </executions>  
  </plugin>  
  </plugins>  
  </build>  
</project>
```

Here are the commands I use to deploy the feature:

> fabric:version-create 1.1
>   fabric:profile-create --parent jboss-fuse-full fuse-poc
>   fabric:profile-edit --repository mvn:com.myorg.fuse/feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features fuse-poc 1.1
>
> fabric:profile-edit --feature fuse-poc-camel fuse-poc 1.1
>   fabric:profile-edit --feature fuse-poc-activemq fuse-poc 1.1
>
> fabric:container-upgrade 1.1 root
>   fabric:container-add-profile root fuse-poc

After I manually do `osgi:refresh <bundle id>` the bundle it starts fine.

> fabric:container-remove-profile root fuse-poc

All the config pid entries stay in the config, and all osgi bundles are also staying installed. How do i correctly undeploy artifacts so that the container is clean and an updated version of the same artifact can be deployed without side effects?

I suspect i am doing something conceptually wrong, because ultimately the issue above leads to the following problem: if i add a property to either the  element in features, or the .cfg file and install the project using maven again, and then do container-remove-profile, profile-refresh, and container-add-profile, the config does not change at all. It can only be redeployed correctly if i manually do the config:delete command on my pid in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally had time to dig through the sources and cross-reference karaf, fabric and jboss documentation.
Here is how it works:

- The code responsible for loading/unloading bundles through the feature repository system is located in fabric-agent-1.2.0.redhat-621084.jar
- Notably, the class io.fabric8.agent.service.FeatureConfigInstaller is responsible for the configuration entries, and the class io.fabric8.agent.service.Agent is doing the overall deployment
- There is no code at all to uninstall the config file/remove config entries. This makes it troublesome to do development with SNAPSHOTs
- However, there is a useful 'override' property that can be specified on the `<configfile>` element - if it is set to true, the config PID file will be overwritten on deployment which is exactly what i wanted for local development
- For `<config>` element, there is an undocumented 'append' property, which, when set to true, is supposed to append new entries to the config. However, it is hilariously bugged - turns out it also removes all defined previously existing properties when trying to append. Conclusion - use `<configfile>` functionality instead
- Additionally, for externalizing environment configuration i've come to the conclusion the most simple way is to produce multiple feature xml descriptors from the same file through different maven build profiles. The project files consequently look like this:

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myorg.fuse</groupId>
        <artifactId>fuse-poc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>feature</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <name>FUSE PoC Feature Repository</name>

    <properties>
        <build.environment>dev</build.environment>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>target/classes/fuse-poc.xml</file>
                                    <type>xml</type>
                                    <classifier>features-${build.environment}</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>src/main/resources/env/${build.environment}/com.myorg.fuse.poc.cfg</file>
                                    <type>cfg</type>
                                    <classifier>${build.environment}</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <build.environment>local-dev</build.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <build.environment>dev</build.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>      
        <profile>
            <id>uat</id>
            <properties>
                <build.environment>uat</build.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.environment>prod</build.environment>
            </properties>
        </profile>      
    </profiles>
</project>
```

feature.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="fuse-poc">
    <feature name="fuse-poc-common" version="${project.version}">
        <bundle>mvn:com.myorg.fuse/common/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name="fuse-poc-camel" version="${project.version}">
        <feature>fuse-poc-common</feature>
        <configfile finalname="etc/com.myorg.fuse.poc.cfg" override="true">
            mvn:com.myorg.fuse/feature/${project.version}/cfg/${build.environment}
        </configfile>
        <bundle>mvn:com.myorg.fuse/fuse-poc-camel/${project.version}</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

This way you can directly specify the environment when creating the profile for deploying the feature:

```
fabric:profile-create --parent jboss-fuse-full fuse-poc fabric:profile-edit --repository mvn:com.myorg.fuse/feature/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xml/features-local-dev fuse-poc
```

Note to set up the build integration tool to build the feature module for all profiles except 'local-dev', since that one needs to be used by developers locally and should not be downloaded from the central repository

On a final note, once i resolved the config handling issues and the bundles started deploying correctly, the platform also started undeploying bundles correctly on removing the profile from the container. I suspect there is some issue with uninstalling the bundles whenever the original deployment ended in failure